# Remote Desktop Connection - How to get the certificate prompt back?

Tags: remote-desktop, certificate

I just tried remoting to my work PC from home and got the "identity cannot be verified" prompt like the one below. I marked the "Don't ask me again for connections to this computer" box, and then accidentally clicked No *(do not connect)* instead of Yes.  Now when I try to connect it asks me for my password, but then it does not connect and it goes back to the RDC login prompt.

How can I undo this setting?  I looked in the MMC Certificates snap-ins, but did not find anything that looks related to my work computer.  I also tried deleting Default.rdp, but there's nothing relevant in that file either.  Any help is much appreciated!

[image: Remote Desktop Connection Certificate prompt]

Comment: In the connection dialog if you click *Options*, then click the *Advanced* tab you can choose what to do if the server cannot be verified. Make sure it's not set to 'Do Not Connect'.

Comment: James, thanks for replying. I've tried each of the options there, and even "Connect and don't warn me" results in the same behavior, so I think my mistake with the "Don't ask me again" setting is overriding this.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

1. Open Registry Editor (regedit.exe)
2. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers`
3. Delete the connection info for the computer that you want to reset

The next time you log in, type the name, and the request returns.

I tested this.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!!

Comment: It seems like it doesn't work for Windows 8.. can't get certificate warning back..

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The correct entry to delete is `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server\Client\LocalDevices\<name>`.

Comment: You're both correct. `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\LocalDevices\<name>` is for the message "the publisher of this remote connection can't be identified. Do you want to connect anyway? This remote connection could harm your local or remote computer".



`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers` is for the second prompt after login (the certificate portion), "the identity of the remote computer cannot be verified. Do you want to connect anyway?"

Comment: While very useful for the Windows Remote Desktop Connection application, this does not work for the Microsoft Remote Desktop store app. The store app does not save settings or certificates to the registry.

Comment: A third key is sometimes involved. If the RDP file is properly signed by [rdpsign](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rdpsign), the first prompt becomes "Don't ask me again for remote connections from this publisher." If you check that, instead of going into the `LocalDevices` list, the thumbprint of the signing certificate is written to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\PublisherBypassList`. Future connections to computers signed by the same certificate do not raise the first warning. To get the warning back, delete that entry.

Comment: I think we don't need to delete the entire key (i.e., *the connection info for the computer that you want to reset*). In the `...\Servers\<Hostname or IP>` registry key, deleting the `CertHash` value (type is **REG_BINARY**) is enough. Other information, such as `UsernameHint` (the auto-filled username when prompted), is also stored in the key.

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me as well in Windows 7. Due to this issue, I was strangely unable to login to RDP.

These are the steps I have done

1) Remove the Default.rdf from Documents folder. It will be hidden 
2) Remove the RDP connection folder using regedit in the following folder 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client\Servers
3) Run mmc.exe. Add Snap In -> Cerificates -> Computer Account -> Local Computer -> Finish
   Expand the Added Certificate -> Remote Desktop folder and remove the certificate issued.
4) Do Step 3 in remote desktop as well

Thanks,
Sarath